# mixed="true" in XML XSD

Tags: xml, xsd

I am using the following XSD:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified">
  <xs:element name="root">
    <xs:complexType mixed="true">
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="value" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="5" type="new_type"/>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
  <xs:complexType name="new_type" mixed="true">
    <xs:choice>
      <xs:element name="function"/>
      <xs:element name="something_else"/>
    </xs:choice>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

The following XML file fails  on line: abc

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
  xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="test.xsd" 
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">  
    <value><function/></value>
    <value><function/></value>
    <value>abc</value>
    abc
</root>
```

Despite mixed="true" for complexType new_type on line 11 of XML, the validation of this XML file fails since it expects an element specified within xs:choice.

I need to be able to specify just a value in addition to element .

How should I change my XSD file?

Thanks,

Boris

Answer (score 2):

If you add `minOccurs="0"` to your `<xsd:choice>`, it will validate:

```
  <xs:complexType name="new_type" mixed="true">
    <xs:choice minOccurs="0">
      <xs:element name="function"/>
      <xs:element name="something_else"/>
    </xs:choice>
  </xs:complexType>
```

Otherwise, you need to have one element *in addition* to any character data you may have in it.